# R Studio Collapsing does not save

Tags: r, rstudio

My code consists of too many lines of code (LOC) and therefore I am using 'ALT + L' (i.e. Edit/Folding/Collapse in the menu of RStudio) to remove certain code chunks temporarily, to get a better overview of my project. The chunks are then replaced by a little two-sided arrow in the editor, which can be clicked to expand the chunks and make the code visible again. I call this 'Collapsing' in the following.

Here comes the problem: Some of the Collapsing is saved when I close my project, whereas other parts seem to automatically expand when I restart my project (unintentionally).

Is there any way to control this behavior? I would like to permanently collapse the code and only expand, if I click on the two-sided arrow.

Comment: I don't use the RStudio IDE, but this sounds like it should be a [feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues) ... unfortunately, it might be an ideal question for SO, so I won't be terribly surprised if you don't get much feedback. (Or you'll get the one perfect comment/answer.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks, I will check that. Well I don't really understand the currently implemented behavior, because sometimes it seems to save and sometimes not. Seems to be more like a bug to me. Possibly due to changing projects/reopening projects or files.

Comment: They call it "folding", btw. From [their docs](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections): *"Folded regions are preserved while editing a document; however all foldable regions are shown expanded by default when a file is closed and re-opened."* From that, it sounds intentional. Are you certain that *"some of the Collapsing is saved when [you] close [your] project"*?

Comment: @r2evans yes one region is certainly collapsed, it hasn't changed for example when I opened my project today and did not do any folding at all. I guess my intended behavior is actually unintentional and seems to be a bug. Would be really nice to have that as a feature though - being able to save the folding.

Comment: Though I wouldn't think that that would be a high priority for them (and their issue-list is over 900 at the moment), it's a fair and legitimate requested feature. I suspect others may latch onto it as well, and often any spare dev time is focused on higher-popularity requested features. Of course, if you can offer them a PR, it's more likely ...

Comment: Ok thanks. Let's see, maybe at some point they will add this feature.

Comment: As long as "Restore previously open source documents at startup" is active, all folded code is saved. If I keep the script open in RStudio and close RStudio rather than the script, all folding is saved upon opening RStudio. See [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/wish-store-state-of-collapsible-code-tree/492/2).